# How to format keyboard keys (i.e. <kbd>) on slack?

Tags: slack

Is there a way to format keys like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> in slack chat?

Here on stack overflow, this is achieved with `<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>` which yields <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. Is there a way to do this in slack chat?

Comment: I was also looking for this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd but wasn't able to find anything in the slack docs